# javascript should open a random page after 7 seconds, but how?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redirect, random, settimeout

I have this html page, with javascript code, but I can not get the code to open one of the cases 3 pages, the settimeout works, but to connect the random selected page work, I have enclosed the code cf. below, if I am some skilled javascript people who can tell what needs to be done to make it work I would be grateful.

the browser open this up
http://localhost:62206/'sitelist[ran]'

my html and javascript code below here

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script language="Javascript">
        var sitelist = new array;
        sitelist[0] = "www.ford.com";
        sitelist[1] = "www.bmw.com";
        sitelist[2] = "www.mercedes.com";
 
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * sitelist.length);
    </script>

   
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            setTimeout(function () { location.href = "'sitelist[ran]'" }, 7000);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you doing well, here are some minor changes to your code to solve your problems, i'll answer to questions if necessary.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script language="Javascript">
        var sitelist = [];
        sitelist[0] = "https://www.ford.com/";
        sitelist[1] = "https://www.bmw.com/fr/index.html";
        sitelist[2] = "https://www.mercedes-benz.com/en/";
 
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * sitelist.length);
    </script>

   
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = sitelist[ran] }, 7000);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi thanks

I try your code but still the same

the browsers url show this: http://localhost:62605/undefined

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: you get http://localhost:62605/undefined after 7 second when you try to access http://localhost:62605/ with my code ? because i opened a wamp for this and reloaded the page 5 times to get all 3 sites and all load well

Comment: thanks Kheops

But your code in visual studio does not works, your code below here

<body onload="myFunction()">

    <h1>Hello World3!</h1>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            const listNumber = urlParams.get('siteList')
            //console.log(siteList)
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = sitelist[listNumber] }, 7000);
        }
    </script>

</body>

Comment: but your new code is ok, thanks a lot

Comment: You can upvote the answer and close it I think, have a great day

Comment: how can I upvote the answer, I am quit new here in this forum

Comment: oh I find the way, your solution is upvote :-)

Comment: I get this message;  Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. :-(

Answer (score 0):

It is `Array()` not `array`.

And you wrapped the `sitelist[ran]` in `"' '"` for some reason, remove that.

When you use quotes, you create a string, but I don't think that's what you want to do there.

Comment: thanks I change to new Array()

It does not solve the main problem

The array do not open one of the 3 random sites :-(

Comment: read the rest of the answer

Answer (score 0):

or you can just declare it as simple as that

```
var sitelist = [];
```

Comment: thanks 

But no reactions and the visual studio show this warning

"(JS) An element access expression should take an argument"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).